# Matlab - converting Recursive Functions to Iterative Functions

Tags: function, matlab, loops, recursion, if-statement

I know its possible in Java and C++ etc, but is this possible in Matlab?
I've recently discovered Matlab doesnt have short cuts like `value++` instead they have to use `value = value+1` so i'm wondering whether its possible to convert this function to an iterative one. I'm not sure where to start. If so, is it less beneficial than a recursive function?

```
    function [lines] = recurse(R,C, lines, T_l, count, directions)
    [rows, columns] = size(lines);
    if((R < 2 || C < 2) || (R > rows-1 || C > columns - 1) || count>500)
        count= count+1;
        return;
    end
    count= count+1;
    direction = directions(R,C);
            if(direction >= 68 || direction <=-68)                                          
                if(lines(R-1,C) > T_l)
                    lines(R-1,C) = 0;
                    lines = recurse(R-1,C, lines, T_l, count, directions);
                end
                if(lines(R+1,C) > T_l)
                    lines(R+1,C) = 0;
                    lines = recurse(R+1,C, lines, T_l, count, directions);
                end
            elseif (direction <= -23 && direction >-68)                                     
                if(lines(R+1,C+1) > T_l)
                    lines(R+1,C+1) = 0;
                    lines = recurse(R+1,C+1, lines, T_l, count, directions);
                end
                if(lines(R-1,C-1) > T_l)
                    lines(R-1,C-1) = 0;
                    lines = recurse(R-1,C-1, lines, T_l, count, directions);
                end
            elseif (direction >= 23 && direction < 68)                                      
                if(lines(R+1,C-1) > T_l)
                    lines(R+1,C-1) = 0;
                    lines = recurse(R+1,C-1, lines, T_l, count, directions);
                end
                if(lines(R-1,C+1) > T_l)
                    lines(R-1,C+1) = 0;                                                     
                    lines = recurse(R-1,C+1, lines, T_l, count, directions);
                end
            else                                                                            
                if(lines(R,C+1) > T_l)
                    lines(R,C+1) = 0;                                                           
                    lines = recurse(R,C+1, lines, T_l, count, directions);
                end
                if(lines(R,C-1) > T_l)
                    lines(R,C-1) = 0;
                    lines = recurse(R,C-1, lines, T_l, count, directions);
                end
            end
    lines(R,C) = 255;
    return;
```

Basically, i currently have a function that calls this second function recursively. I was hoping to consolidate this recursive function into the function calling it as a iterative set of commands. 
I'm pretty sure it will be slower but speed isn't an issue for me and i'm interested to see how the loops will work. Thanks.

Comment: 1.  **is this possible in Matlab?** yes, it is.  2.  **If so, is it less beneficial than a recursive function?** no it is not.  it's a trade-off.  iterative vs recursive is pretty much algorithmic and almost language agnostic.  iterative usually is a little more complicated and more difficult to understand but incurs less overhead in stuff like stack frame set up, and it can even potentially require less memory (although this is not always true).

Comment: one way to convert your recursive function to an iterative one is to recognize what is being stored on the stack.  see how much of it is absolutely necessary.  for whatever is necessary, create a stack-like structure to store it, and then operate on that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish `value++` using  [`operator`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/operator.html)  (you will need the symbolic toolbox though).

`operator(symb, f, T, prio)` defines a new operator symbol `symb` of type `T` (Prefix | Postfix | Binary | Nary) with priority `prio`. The function `f` evaluates expressions using the new operator.

Given the operator symbol "++", say, with evaluating function `f`, the following expressions are built by the parser, depending on the type of the operator, where :

**Prefix**:     The input ++x results in f(x).

**Postfix**:    The input x++ results in f(x).

**Binary**:     The input x ++ y ++ z results in f(f(x, y), z).

**Nary**:       The input x ++ y ++ z results in f(x, y, z)).

see more at matlab's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/operator.html).